# Tridion 2013 sp1 content manager - error retrieving item with id

Tags: content-manager

Encountered error as below in content manager when trying to display component details

[image]

It happens after the database name was changed after migration.

**Event Log**

[image]

Comment: Check if you can access the database from the server where CMS is installed. Also provide the error detail from Event log.

Comment: I'm able to access the content manager database using MS SQL and also the broker DB using Sesame Data Browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue, please verify the following steps:

- Ensure that the MSDTC settings enabled on both the Content Manager server and the Database server.
- Go to "Administrative Tools > Component Services"
- On the left navigation tree, go to "Component Services > Computers > My Computer" (you may need to double click and wait as some nodes
  need time to expand)
- Right click on "My Computer", select "Properties"
- Select "MSDTC" tab
- Click "Security Configuration"
- Make sure you check "Network DTC Access", "Allow Remote Client",
  "Allow Inbound/Outbound", "Enable TIP" (Some option may not be
  necessary, have a try to get your configuration)
- The service will restart

On your client computer use the same above procedure to open the
"Security Configuration" setting, make sure you check "Network DTC
Access", "Allow Inbound/Outbound" option, restart service and computer
if necessary.

On you SQL server service manager, click "Service" dropdown, select
"Distribute Transaction Coordinator", it should be also running on
your server computer.

[image]

To verify this, open the "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security” MMC and enable the rules highlighted in the screenshot below:

Hope it helps.

[image]